# Java example for encrypting pwd with whirlpool algorithm using gnu-crypto jar

Tags: java

I want to encrypt a String using gnu.crypto.hash.Whirlpool hashing.

The encrypt should encrypt the password and should return the encrypted pwd.
encrypt(pwd);

> This method should have implementation for encrypting pwd using gnu jars and whirlpool
>       hashing algorithm
>    which should be equal to the pwd generated by the below site
>    http://hash.online-convert.com/whirlpool-generator

I tried with the code below but I am unable to get the 512 byets code similar to the whirlpool site generated:

```
import gnu.crypto.hash.HashFactory;
import gnu.crypto.hash.IMessageDigest;

  public class EncryptPwdWithAPI{
public static void main(String arg[])
{
         encrypt("somepwd");
    }
public static String encrypt(String password)
{
IMessageDigest md = HashFactory.getInstance("WHIRLPOOL");
md.update(input, 0, input.length); 
byte[] digest = md.digest(); 
System.out.println( "Input : "+new String(input)+ "\nPWD : "+new String(digest)
}
```

}

Comment: Please don't include a 'sig.' in posts, never include an email address, and show some effort of your own - SO is not a help-desk.

Comment: :) I tried with the below but I am unable to get the 512 byets code similar to the whirlpool site generated.                   IMessageDigest md = HashFactory.getInstance("WHIRLPOOL");
       md.update(input, 0, input.length);
      
      byte[] digest = md.digest();
      System.out.println(
        "Input : "+new String(input)+
        "\nPWD : "+new String(digest)
        );

Comment: When I use the bouncycastle library's implementation of Whirlpool I get the same output as PHP's.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ya correct but i was expecting whirlpool hascode with 512 bytes which is equal to the code generated by the online hashcode generator. **I got the intended output with [JacksumAPI](http://www.jonelo.de/java/jacksum/)**.

Here's some code:

```
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import jonelo.jacksum.JacksumAPI;
import jonelo.jacksum.algorithm.AbstractChecksum;

public class JacksumTest {
    public static void main(String arg[])
    {
        String password = "somepwd";
        AbstractChecksum checksum = null; 
        try { 
           checksum = JacksumAPI.getChecksumInstance("whirlpool"); 
           checksum.update(password.getBytes());
           System.out.println(checksum.getFormattedValue());
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae) { }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are directly using the byte values as character values instead you should convert the byte array to hex or base64 encoding to compare it to the values on the whirlpool site. Apache Commons Codec provides hex and base64 functions.

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
...
  Base64.encodeBase64String(digest);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but it is not returning the result same as generated by                                                                    [link] http://hash.online-convert.com/whirlpool-generator

Answer (score 0):

@Eelke is correct, but This is how you do it, encoded password should be in the result variable.

```
    IMessageDigest oldencoder = HashFactory.getInstance(Registry.WHIRLPOOL_HASH);

    byte[] input = password.getBytes();

    oldencoder.update(input, 0, input.length);

    byte[] digest = oldencoder.digest();

    result = gnu.crypto.util.Util.toString(digest).toLowerCase();
```