# Jacksum NoSuchAlgorithmException

Tags: java, hash, whirlpool

I'm trying to use the Jacksum API to [generate a Whirlpool hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11921334/java-example-for-encrypting-pwd-with-whirlpool-algorithm-using-gnu-crypto-jar), but I'm getting a NoSuchAlgorithmException:

```
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import jonelo.jacksum.JacksumAPI;
import jonelo.jacksum.algorithm.AbstractChecksum;

public static String genHash(String inText) {

    AbstractChecksum checksum = null;
    checksum = JacksumAPI.getChecksumInstance("whirlpool");
    checksum.update(inText.getBytes());
    return checksum.getFormattedValue();

}
```

I tried other popular algorithms (sha256, md5) and they all apparently "aren't such".

```
./libsdpg.java:27: error: unreported exception NoSuchAlgorithmException; must be caught or declared to be thrown
    checksum = JacksumAPI.getChecksumInstance("whirlpool");
                                             ^
1 error
```

EDIT: I added the try-catch, and now it's actually getting the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not actually "getting" an exception. The compiler is telling you that you have failed to appropriately handle a checked exception.

The `JacksumAPI#getChecksumInstance(java.lang.String)` method throws a checked exception called `NoSuchAlgorithmException`. A checked exception must either be explicitly handled (using `try-catch`), or the enclosing method must declare that it throws it by including it in its signature. So your options are:

```
try {
   ...
   checksum = JacksumAPI.getChecksumInstance("whirlpool");
   ...
} catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
   //handle the exception
}
```

or change your method signature to:

```
public static String genHash(String inText) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    ...
}
```

Keep in mind with the second option you have merely pushed the handling up to a higher level (i.e., where `genHash` is called); you will essentially have to handle it at some point.

Comment: I added the try-catch and now the error is actually happening.

Comment: Well, not a compiler error, but the exception is run (`//handle the exception`) in your code

Comment: So when running you are getting an exception during runtime? Then that's because you have passed in an invalid argument. Perhaps `"whirlpool"` is not a proper argument? I would read the documentation for Jacksum.

Comment: I think I forgot to recompile after changing the algorithm back to `whirlpool` (I'm new to Java). Working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

You are not getting the `NoSuchAlgorithmException`. Instead the compiler is saying that the `getChecksumInstance()` throws a checked exception, `NoSuchAlgorithmException` which needs to be handled, since you've not already done that.

You can do that either by having a throws clause in your `genHash()`(you'll need to handle the exception in the method where `genHash()` is called though)

```
// Solution 1
public static String genHash(String inText) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
```

or by surrounding the call to `getChecksumInstance()` within a `try-catch`.

```
// Solution 2
try {
    checksum = JacksumAPI.getChecksumInstance("whirlpool");
} catch(NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    // Do something on exception
}
```