# Why am I getting an error here in my Scanner input line?

Tags: java

I'm getting an error on my Scanner input line, where I put `(new File(myths.txt))` on the word `File`, it says *can't find symbol class File*.

```
package program6;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class Program6{
String[] StringArray = new String[100];
int[] IntArray = new int[100];
String FileName = "myths.txt";
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File("myths.txt"));
```

Answer (score 1):

you have not imported class `File`.The class `File` is present in `io` package

```
import java.io.File;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an import statement for `File` class.

```
import java.io.File; // import statement for File.
```

Also you can just use the `fileName` to create the new `File` instead of giving the hardcoded name again.

```
String FileName = "myths.txt";
Scanner input = new Scanner(new File(FileName));
```

Since you're creating a new Scanner object using the `new File(fileName)`, this constructor of [`Scanner`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#Scanner%28java.io.File%29) throws a `FileNotFoundException` which needs to be handled.

I advice you move this code to a method inside the class and handle the `FileNotFoundException` either by having a `throws` clause or a `try-catch` around the code creating a new Scanner using a File object.

You can see [an example here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20381922/2024761) on how to handle a checked exception, in your case, `FileNotFoundException`.

Comment: Why would I get an error, unreported exception FileNotFoundException; must be caught or declared to be thrown?

Comment: @user2934545 see this link for checked and unchecked exception http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2013/04/exception-handling-in-java-exception.html

Comment: Couldn't I just add a throws FileNotFoundException somewhere?

Comment: You can add a throws clause, but for that the code needs to be in a method as only a method can have the throws clause. Even if you want to use a try-catch, it must be inside a method and not hanging around in the class.

Comment: If you want them to be instance variables, you can just declare them there and initialize in the method or constructor handling the error in it.

Answer (score 0):

You missed imports. That's why you are getting this error. Add import to your code.

```
import java.io.File;
```